# how to use value as key in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Given this as output of mongo find command

```
{ 
    "cust" : NumberInt(8388), 
    "key" : "T_SUB_CAT", 
    "value" : "98", 
    "tag1" : "T_RECENT_SUB_CAT_1"
},{ 
    "cust" : NumberInt(8388), 
    "key" : "T_SUB_CAT", 
    "value" : "109", 
    "tag1" : "T_RECENT_SUB_CAT_2"
},{ 
    "cust" : NumberInt(8388), 
    "key" : "T_SUB_CAT", 
    "value" : "6", 
    "tag1" : "T_RECENT_SUB_CAT_3"
}
```

how to use aggregation and $project to get **result like** this

```
{ 
    "cust" : NumberInt(8388), 
    "T_RECENT_SUB_CAT_1" : "98", 
    "T_RECENT_SUB_CAT_2" : "109", 
    "T_RECENT_SUB_CAT_3" : "6"
}
```

please help me using **project / aggregate**

thanks a lot

Comment: What doe je mean with key?, you can creat a (Unique) Index on a field, but
there are no foreign key relations in MongoDB see https://docs.mongodb.org

Comment: value of tag1 as column and value,
like 
{
"cust" : NumberInt(8388), 
    "key" : "T_SUB_CAT", 
    "value" : "6", 
    "tag1" : "T_RECENT_SUB_CAT_3"
}

in the above what is required is that result would be like 

{ 
    "cust" : NumberInt(8388), 
 "T_RECENT_SUB_CAT_3" : "6", 
}

hope u understand the requirement.

Comment: key is the name of a column it is nothing spl

Comment: My sincerest advice: don't! But if you insist: it would be nice if you showed us what you tried so far. Oh, and comments are explicitly there to ask for clarification. You don't want to rebuke anybody, because that might be the very person with the answer to your question.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in Mongo - it seems far easier to me to do it in the calling javascript

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg i am sorry,
i just import the data from csv file, now what i am trying to do is to manupulate it.

Comment: @JanBluemink please try to understand the question,  i dont seem any pk, fk relation here

Comment: Again: Don't use values as keys. While it might be appealing in the (very) short term, it becomes a pain in the neck _very_ soon. Focus on finding out how to answer the questions you have on your data based on what the import gives you.

Comment: There are some basic principles that you seem to be missing here apart from the general "good advice" here to simply not reshape values to keys. ( Trust us, it's really bad design to do so ). 1. The aggregation framework does **does not** do this, and I'll go so far to say **will not** since it's a really bad idea anyway. 2. The only other "reshaping" option is therefore `mapReduce`, but of course just like the aggregation framework such "reshaping" is complete overkill ( chainsaw to slice ham overkill ) since there is no attempt to "aggregate/reduce" anything.

Comment: If all you want is to reshape each returned document, then just manipulate each document returned in your database client code. Even in other databases, such renaming for renamings sake on the server side is really a waste of resources.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg that what my requirement is.

Comment: friends i find a solution,
using while loop.

put all result in a var say cust2,

while(cust2.hasNext()){
  var document = cust2.next();
  db.<collection>.update(
   { cust: document.cust,
     tag1:document.tag1 
     },
   {
       cust:document.cust ,
         tag1:document.tag1 ,
     key:document.key,
     value:document.value
     
      },
      {upsert:true}
      
)
}



Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put all result in a var say cust2,

```
while(cust2.hasNext()){ 
var document = cust2.next(); db.<collection>.update( 
{ cust: document.cust, tag1:document.tag1 }, 
{ cust:document.cust , tag1:document.tag1 , 
key:document.key, value:document.value }, 
{upsert:true} 
) }
```